# What should I do when transfer development mode into production mode in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using Rails 3.

Environment

Mac : Nginx + Passenger 4.0 + Ruby 2.0 (RVM)

Under Mac , I can run my app under development mode (by rails server) very well,

But When I run nginx on , it shows me the error . and not work even I run bundle install

```
git://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails.git (at master) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install` (Bundler::GitError)
```

and In another environment, Ubuntu.

I also got some problem when I run the app from development mode into production mode.

RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile

I have no idea totally, I don't think it's css problem?

maybe it didn't install some gem or do some pre-requirement work in production mode

Please give me some tips , thanks a lot

```
rake aborted!
Invalid CSS after "background-color: ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "#white;"
  (in /Volumes/COMMON/Dropbox/rails/zeus/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
(sass):1738
/Users/poc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1145:in `expected'
/Users/poc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/script/lexer.rb:199:in `expected!'
/Users/poc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/script/parser.rb:471:in `assert_expr'
/Users/poc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/script/parser.rb:49:in `parse'
/Users/poc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1021:in `sass_script'
/Users/poc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:881:in `value!'
/Users/poc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:858:in `declaration'
/Users/poc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:581:in `block in declaration_or_ruleset'
/Users/poc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1121:in `call'
/Users/poc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1121:in `rethrow'
/Users/poc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:591:in `declaration_or_ruleset'
```

nginx setting

```
 18     passenger_root /Users/poc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.18;
 19     passenger_ruby /Users/poc/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p247/ruby;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say your command line Ruby is the RVM version but you haven't let Passenger know about your RVM ruby so it uses the default system Ruby. Start here: http://rvm.io/integration/passenger to check that you have Passenger and Apache properly configured to use the correct Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

> git://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails.git (at master) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install` (Bundler::GitError)

Try run `bundle install --deployment`

> rake aborted!
>   Invalid CSS after "background-color: ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "#white;"
>     (in /Volumes/COMMON/Dropbox/rails/zeus/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
>   (sass):1738

Try `background-color: white;` or `background-color: #FFF;`